# UIView drawRect leak with CoreText

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, core-text

I have a leak that I can't track down.  I am new to CoreText (and C in general) so please be gentle!  The static analyser doesn't show any problems but Instruments does in this method:

```
- (void)drawAttributedStringInBubbleInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    static CGFloat const kTextInset = 10;

    // Add the text to the bubble using an ellipse path inside the main speech bubble if the text property is set
    if (text) {

        // Create an attributed string from the text property
        NSMutableAttributedString *bubbleText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];        

        // Justify the text by adding a paragraph style
        CFIndex stringLength = CFAttributedStringGetLength((CFAttributedStringRef)bubbleText);
        CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTJustifiedTextAlignment;
        CTParagraphStyleSetting _settings[] = {
            {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment}
        };      
        CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(_settings, sizeof(_settings) / sizeof(_settings[0]));
        CFRange stringRange = CFRangeMake(0, stringLength);
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)bubbleText, stringRange, kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);
        CFRelease(paragraphStyle);      

        // Layout the text within an elliptical frame
        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)bubbleText);

        // Create elliptical path that is inset from the frame of the view
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGRect drawingRect = self.bounds;
        drawingRect.origin.x = kTextInset;
        drawingRect.origin.y = kTextInset;
        drawingRect.size.width -= 2 * kTextInset;
        drawingRect.size.height -= 2 * kTextInset;
        CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, drawingRect);

        // Create a text frame from the framesetter and the path 
        CTFrameRef textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,CFRangeMake(0,0), path, NULL);

        // Draw the text frame in the view's graphics context
        CTFrameDraw(textFrame, context);

        // Clean up
        CGPathRelease(path);
        CFRelease(framesetter);
        [bubbleText release];
    }
}
```

The main culprit according to Instruments is the `CTFrameRef textFrame =` line, although I thought I have released everything properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the culprit, the [Core Foundation rule for `Create`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) methods are you have to release them. Apple releases it properly in an example in the [Core Text Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html).

```
    // Clean up
    CGPathRelease(path);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(textFrame);
```

Comment: thanks.  Worked a treat. Can't believe I missed this. Appreciate the quick response, the reasoning and the extra links.  Cheers Dave.